# Find point on line withv given start point, distance, and line equation

Tags: geometry

I have line equation  $$   Ax +By + C = 0.$$

I have start point (on this line): $    P_0 = (X_0, Y_0)$. 
I have distance $d$ too.

I need find point $P_2$ with distance $d$ from $P_0$ and placed on this line. I know that we have 2 points with this distance. But how calculate? I need some programmatic solution.

Comment: Intersect the circle with center $P$ and radius $d$ with the line.

Comment: Hint: what are the coordinates $x$ and $y$ if the point is on the line? How to compute distance? Solve an equation.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio that is great idea but i have problem to implement this as a programming method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the equation $Ax+By+C = 0$, find the slope of the straight line:
$$A\cdot{\Delta x} + B\cdot{\Delta y} = 0$$
As long as $B\ne 0$, $\Delta y = -\frac AB \Delta x$. Also it is known that
$$d = \sqrt{(\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta x)^2} = \left|\Delta x\right| \sqrt{1+\frac {A^2}{B^2}}$$
So $\Delta y$ and $\Delta x$ can be solved (and there are two pairs of $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$).

If $B=0$, the straight line is a vertical line and $\Delta y$ is pretty easy to solve; but using similar reasoning, $\Delta x = 0$ and then
$$d = \sqrt{(\Delta y)^2 + (\Delta x)^2} = \left|\Delta y\right| \sqrt{1+0}$$

Comment: could you show me your idea on some example? I have some problem with understand yout equations

Comment: great, really thanks , i think only which solution is better , your or @Martin R

Answer (score 1):

$(A, B)$ is a *normal vector* for the line, therefore $v = (-B, A)$ is a *direction
vector* and you get all points on the line with

$$
   (x, y) = P_0 + t \, v = (X_0, Y_0) + t (-B, A), \quad t \in \mathbb R.
$$

Now choose $t$ such that the length of $t(−B,A)$ is equal to the given distance $d$,
this gives the two points

$$
  (X_2, Y_2) = (X_0, Y_0)  \pm \frac d{\sqrt { A^2 + B^2}} (-B, A) \quad .
$$